# finding an orthogonal subspace to $span\{(i,0,1)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't understand how to find an orthogonal subspace to $span\{(i,0,1)\}$. All my efforts give me the same element at least once. Any thoughts?

Comment: i have my answer. Certainly (0,1,0)*(i,0,1) =0 and (i,0,1)*(i,0,1)*(i,0,1)=0

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathsf v=(i,0,1)$. Presumably you would like to describe
$$
V=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{\mathsf v\}^{\bot}
$$
By definition,
\begin{align*}
V
&= \{\mathsf x\in\Bbb C^3 :\mathsf y\in\Span\{\mathsf v\}\Rightarrow \langle\mathsf x,\mathsf  y\rangle=0\} \\
&= \{\mathsf x\in\Bbb C^3:\lambda\in\Bbb C\Rightarrow\langle\mathsf x,\lambda\mathsf v\rangle=0\} \\
&= \{\mathsf x\in\Bbb C^3:\lambda\in\Bbb C\Rightarrow \lambda \langle\mathsf x,\mathsf v\rangle=0\} \\
&= \{\mathsf x\in\Bbb C^3:\langle\mathsf x,\mathsf v\rangle=0\} \\
&= \{\mathsf x\in\Bbb C^3:i x_1+x_3=0\} \\
&= \{\mathsf x\in\Bbb C^3:x_3=-i x_1\} \\
&= \Span\{(0,1,0),(1,0,-i)\}
\end{align*}

In other words, the $\Bbb C^3$-vectors orthogonal to $(i,0,1)$ are exactly the vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ satifying $x_3=-ix_1$. Hence every vector orthogonal to $(i,0,1)$ may be written as
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,x_2,-ix_1)=x_1\cdot(1,0,-i)+x_2\cdot(0,1,0)
$$
Thus the space you are looking for is 
$$
V=\Span\{(0,1,0),(1,0,-i)\}
$$
This space consists of all vectors of the form
$$
\lambda_1\cdot(0,1,0)+\lambda_2\cdot(1,0,-i)=(\lambda_2,\lambda_1,-i\lambda_2)
$$
for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Bbb C$. Note that $V$ is a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb C^3$.

Comment: I agree that (0,1,0)*(i,0,1)=0, a good answer, that I had previously gotten. I also got (1,0,-i). However, it is a scalar multiple of (i,0,1): i*(1,0,-i)=(i,0,1). Graphically. I draw these

Comment: I agree that (0,1,0)*(1,0,-i)=0, a good answer, that I had previously gotten. I also got (1,0,-i)*(i,0,1)=0. However,    (1,0,-i) is a scalar multiple of (i,0,1): i*(1,0,-i)=(i,0,1). I must be missing something.

Comment: @JimBrown Do you understand the definition of $\operatorname{Span}$?

Answer (score 0):

Think about this. Let $x$ be any vector lying in the orthogonal subspace to $y=(i,0,1)$, then what can you say about $<x,y>$, the complex inner product? what kind of surface does it describe? Is it a vector space? If so what is its dimension?